# The uphill battle for /alpine

Tags: discussion, tags

On this site, Alpine can refer to [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux), a Linux distribution, or to [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_(email_client)), an email client (an open source rewrite of Pine). Until a few minutes ago, both used the tag [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine). Out of 26 questions with the tag:

- 16 referred to the email client, and I left them tagged [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine);
- 10 referred to the distribution, and I retagged 8 to [alpine-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux) and removed the tag from the 2 others because the distribution was only incidental to the question.

While the email client has the majority, this seems to be changing quickly: out of 11 questions with the tag posted in 2016, 9 referred to the distribution. Should we rename the tag for the email client?

Answer (score 8):

[alpine-mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-mail) should work, providing [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine) is removed so people can't inadvertently use it.

Comment: I like this; perhaps alpine could be a synonym to alpine-mail? Having alpine-linux makes it similar to our other Linux distribution tags. I can only hope that askers would read the tag excerpts.

Comment: Sorry this was overlooked for so long. It's [fixed now](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4747/73) using your suggested tag name; the alpine tag is deleted