# Alpine and Alpine-Linux tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I frequently observe that people inadvertently choose the tag [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine) (an email client) instead of [alpine-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux). See the recent question [sshpass not functioning in alpine linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417405/sshpass-not-functioning-in-alpine-linux).

I suggest to remove the tag [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine) and replace it with [alpine-email-client](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-email-client) or another variation. There is a relevant discussion in [The uphill battle for /alpine](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4184).

Comment: Just waiting for someone to be using alpine on alpine!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I moved all existing [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine) posts into either [alpine-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux) or [alpine-mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-mail). I also put in a request to blacklist the tag since it still exists on Stack Overflow (where it's the distro), Super User (where it's the mail client), and Server Fault (where it's not specified), and all of them migrate to us regularly.

---

**Edit**: I'm told that now that the tag is fully deleted, migrations won't recreate it. So [alpine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine) isn't blacklisted, but it will stay gone unless somebody [recreates it manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).